# JS join is defaulted to comma?

Tags: javascript

The below code is working fine,
It prints:

```
pigs1,goats1,sheep1
pigs2,goats2,sheep2
pigs3,goats3,sheep3
```

My question is how can I control the delimiter between words (currently defaulted to comma)
For example to print with pound delimiter:

```
pigs1#goats1#sheep1
pigs2#goats2#sheep2
pigs3#goats3#sheep3
```

Or no delimiter ?

```
pigs1goats1sheep1
pigs2goats2sheep2
pigs3goats3sheep3
```

```js
const animals1 = ['pigs1', 'goats1', 'sheep1'];
const animals2 = ['pigs2', 'goats2', 'sheep2'];
const animals3 = ['pigs3', 'goats3', 'sheep3'];

var buffer = []; 

buffer.push(animals1);
buffer.push(animals2);
buffer.push(animals3);

console.log(buffer.join('\n'));
```

Comment: Based on the documentation yes, the default is comma which states `The join() method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated by commas or a specified separator string.` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: Read the documentation....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `join` function on your arrays with any string as delimiter.

```js
const animals1 = ['pigs1', 'goats1', 'sheep1'];
const animals2 = ['pigs2', 'goats2', 'sheep2'];
const animals3 = ['pigs3', 'goats3', 'sheep3'];

var buffer = []; 

buffer.push(animals1.join('#'));
buffer.push(animals2.join('#'));
buffer.push(animals3.join('#'));

console.log(buffer.join('\n'));
```

Use empty string for no delimiter

```js
animals1.join('') // pigs1goats1sheep1
```

**EDIT**:

If you don't use `join` on your arrays before pushing them, you'll have an array containing array items, your `buffer` looks like this:

```js
[
  [ 'pigs1', 'goats1', 'sheep1' ],
  [ 'pigs2', 'goats2', 'sheep2' ],
  [ 'pigs3', 'goats3', 'sheep3' ]
]
```

By using the final `buffer.join('\n')`, the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) says:

> The string conversions of all array elements are joined into one string.

This means that the elements which are arrays are getting converted into string

```js
[ 'pigs1', 'goats1', 'sheep1' ].toString() // 'pigs1,goats1,sheep1'
```

That's why you have to use `join` to chose the delimiter and convert your array into string before pushing it into your buffer.

Comment: so i guess buffer.push(animals1); this will call join?